# Why identical images have different pixels value

Tags: opencv

I can't understand why Iplimage received from video and from file (received from this video) contain different pixels value. This code show it.

```
CvCapture* readerAvi = cvCreateFileCapture( "input.avi" );
//  Grad first frame from input video stream
if(!cvGrabFrame(readerAvi)) {           
    std::cerr << "Could not grab AVI frame." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
IplImage* videoFrame = cvRetrieveFrame(readerAvi); 
if( !videoFrame )
    break;

// Save values of some pixels in file
std::ofstream fout("frame_pixels.txt"); 
for(int y = 170; y < 270; ++y) {
    for(int x = 30; x < 130; ++x) {
        CvScalar s = cvGet2D(videoFrame, y, x );
        fout << "x=" << x << " y=" << y << " " << s.val[0] << " " << s.val[1] << " " << s.val[2] << std::endl;
    }
    fout << "\n";
}
fout.close();
cvSaveImage("temp.jpg", videoFrame);

// Load saved image
videoFrame = cvLoadImage("temp.jpg");
fout.open("image_pixels.txt");  

// Save values of some pixels in file
for(int y = 170; y < 270; ++y) {
    for(int x = 30; x < 130; ++x) {
          CvScalar s = cvGet2D(videoFrame, y, x );                  
          fout << "x=" << x << " y=" << y << " " << s.val[0] << " " << s.val[1] << " " << s.val[2] << std::endl;

          }
    fout << "\n";
    }
fout.close();
```

So why files frame_pixels.txt and image_pixels.txt contain near numbers but not the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't say for sure without seeing the data itself, but it's very likely to be down to compression undergone by the image. If the video came from a set of images, then each of those images will have gone through a second compression when the video was created - e.g. [JPEG compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#JPEG_compression) in the case of MPEG files (more details [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression)). This will cause artefacts on the image. If the image is a still frame taken from the video, when it was saved, it may well have undergone compression.

Whilst the video frame and the still image may *look* comparable by eye, there's almost certainly going to be slight differences as a result of the way images are compressed.

Comment: Not too mention noise. All images in subsequent frames are subject to gaussian noise.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess [lossy compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression) is the answer as JPEG is a lossy file format.  Perhaps you could try capturing in a lossless format?

Answer (score 0):

When you save the frame into "temp.jpg", the JPEG *lossy* compression algorithm reencodes the frame. The pixel values will be slightly altered by the *lossy* algorithm.

That's why when you read the file "temp.jpg" back *some* of the pixel values differ from the original pixel values that you obtained from the frame in the avi file.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCv uses the ffmpeg library for the video decoding and libjpeg for the image decoding,
probably implementations details contribute in making the result different.